Why does mypy not infer types with torch.nn.functional.linear?
I am trying to use mypy for some PyTorch code, and am perplexed why mypy gives an error here:
from torch import FloatTensor
from torch.nn.functional import linear

def foo(x: FloatTensor, y: FloatTensor) -> FloatTensor:
    return linear(x, y)

mypy outputs:
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Tensor", expected "FloatTensor")  [return-value]


Why does torch.nn.functional.linear give a Tensor here? It seems like the type-checker should be able to infer that the output is a FloatTensor.

What is the best way to address the mypy error?



Since the type-checker isn't working as expected, I would say the best thing to do is use Tensor as the type-hint and then try to cast it as a FloatTensor within the function.

There's a lot of weirdness in pytorch around tensors and backwards compatibility. I'm not confident about the details, but I suspect that they made a new tensor class and also maintained the old version for backwards compatibility, resulting in different "tensors" that don't actually inherit from each other, hence the trouble with the type checker.

Huh, alright. @BenGrossmann what would be the purpose of casting to a FloatTensor within the function if I have the type hint as Tensor?

Honestly, I'm not sure, but I'm not used to using type hints in pytorch at all. I figure, however, that the intent behind your type hint is really to make sure that the input is something like a FloatTensor, even if the input is technically of the Tensor type. If you can't get the type checker to throw the error you want, then I thought the next best thing is to get that error when you try to cast the tensor (and possibly use a try-except block to customize the error message).

With that said, maybe the best thing is to remove the type hint altogether and stick to the error message from casting

I suppose you could also have Union[Tensor, FloatTensor] as the type hint

Because torch.nn.linear is annotated in such way - it does not specialize on types. I don't know whether it really preserves type identity (perhaps a TypeVar(bound=Tensor) would be more correct there), but torch's typing is far from perfect. They use a complicated build system, that file isn't on github, grep for def linear in your venv's torch/_C/_nn.pyi - that's where linear comes from. The signature is def linear(input: Tensor, weight: Tensor, bias: Optional[Tensor] = None) -> Tensor: If you think it should be improved, raise a ticket in pytorch repo - it's a stubs issue.
